# Does .NET DateTime access host machine time or virtual machine time?

Tags: c#, citrix

I ran into an issue with an application running in a remote location through a Citrix server. When the application was run in a remote location it logged an event to the database with the time from the remote location even through the user was accessing the application through Citrix.

Did .NET's DateTime.Now somehow "escape" the Citrix container and find the time of the remote machine or is there some other explanation?

Here is the current setup of the application.

- The application logs events to a database in the US
- The remote user is located in Europe and access the application through Citrix which simulates running the application in the US
- The Citrix server machine time is set to the US time

P.S. The application has been updated to query the time from the database when saving in the future.

Comment: never tried citrix before, at least [some question looks promising](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638378/current-date-time-in-java-under-citrix-xenapp-6-5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- Citrix's "time zone redirection" feature is probably the explanation for what you've observed.  The details are specific to what particular Citrix product you are using (which you didn't supply).  You may be able to disable that feature.  Google it, or ask on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).
- Really, you should avoid using `DateTime.Now` in server-based applications.  It should be irrelevant what the server's time zone setting is.  Use `DateTime.UtcNow`, `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`, or `DateTimeOffset.Now`, along with the `TimeZoneInfo` class, as appropriate.  Alternatively, use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).
- To answer the question in the title, you can see the source code for `DateTime.Now` [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1cd5dd408a32124f).  It works as follows:

  1. Call `DateTime.UtcNow`, which itself calls the `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` Win32 API.  This is the system clock.  It is in terms of UTC - not any specific time zone.  If you're running in a VM, typically this system clock is synchronized with time from the host.
  2. Get data about the local machine's time zone.  It uses a truncated version of the complete time zone (for performance reasons), and it caches the data for future reuse.

     *Note that if Citrix is redirecting the time zone, it will affect this step.*
  3. Using the data retrieved, calculate the offset from UTC - for the specific UTC point retrieved in step 1.
  4. Apply the offset to get local time, truncating if `MinTicks` or `MaxTicks` are exceeded in the conversion.
  5. Mark the value calculated in step 4 with `DateTimeKind.Local`, and return it in a `DateTime` struct.

Comment: Well said.  Let's hope the peeps at Noda Time [saw this video](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY?t=8m38s) by Tom Scott, University of Nottingham, prior to rolling one of their own ;)

Comment: @MickyD - Yes, we've all seen that one.  It's good.  Has a few errors, but makes its point.  NodaTime uses the standard tz database, like anything else good in this space. :)